# Sort a unsorted list (li) with nested lists only on first level

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following list that I would like to sort:

```js
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string")
  var lis = $( "li", ".text-error" );
  var vals = [];
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    vals.push(lis[i].innerHTML);
  vals.sort();
  if (sortDescending)
    vals.reverse();
  for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++)
    lis[i].innerHTML = vals[i];
}
window.onload = function() {
  var desc = false;
  sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
  desc = !desc;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="text-error">
   <li>Brush your teeth</li>
   <li>Wash your hands</li>
   <li>Do your homework</li>
   <li>Do not use curse-words</li>
   <li id="files-errorPrincipals">Act polite:
       <ul class="text-error">
          <li class="file-error">Say Hello</li>
          <li class="file-error">Say Goodbye</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="files-error">Always remember:
       <ul id="files-error-list" class="text-error">
          <li class="file-error">Think for yourself</li>
          <li class="file-error">Think twice</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

This works for the first level of list items, but the list items with nested lists are not sorted.

How can I sort all first level list items?

Comment: This is a good case to make recursion. You could check if your <li> contains children of type ul and recall your function. But to make recursion you will have to adapt your sortUnsortedList function to provide the ul element to sort instead of selecting the li element inside of this function

Comment: Your question is confusing. You write: _"This works for the first level of list items"_ and also _"How can I sort all first level list items?"_. Do you want to sort the 2nd level items as well?

Comment: Has this issue been resolved? If not; could you describe you problem in other words and say what isn't working? If it has been resolved then would you mind marking an answer as accepted?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be easier to isolate each context (in your case it seems to be `.text-error`) first and then iterate over those individually.
This example will iterate nested `li`'s on their respective level.

```js
function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
  if (typeof ul == "string") {
    //Get each individual ul/li-context to sort inside
    var contexts = $('.text-error');
    
    //Iterarate over individual contexts
    contexts.each(function(i,ctx){
        //Get first level <li> elements in specific context
        var lis = $(ctx).children('li');

        //Sort the results
        lis.sort(function(a, b){
          var sortResult = $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
          if(sortDescending){ sortResult = 0 - sortResult }
          return sortResult;
        });

        //Append the items
        lis.each(function(i2, li){
            ctx.append(li);
        })
    }) 
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  var desc = false;
  sortUnorderedList("list", desc);
  desc = !desc;
  return false;
}
```

```css
/*CSS for exampe rendering clarity*/
ul{
  font-size: 0.85em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: calc(1em + 2px);
}
li > ul{
  border-top:1px solid gainsboro;
}
li {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 1px;
}
  li li, li ul {
    border-color: silver;
    color:dimgray;
  }
    li li li, li li ul {
      border-color: gainsboro;
      color:gray;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="text-error">
   <li>Brush your teeth</li>
   <li>Wash your hands</li>
   <li>Do your homework</li>
   <li>Do not use curse-words</li>
   <li id="files-errorPrincipals">Act polite:
       <ul class="text-error">
          <li class="file-error">Say Hello</li>
          <li class="file-error">Say Goodbye</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li id="files-error">Always remember:
       <ul id="files-error-list" class="text-error">
          <li class="file-error">Think for yourself</li>
          <li class="file-error">Think twice</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<h3>Bolow is an example illustrating the sorting on single individual levels.</h3>
<ul class="text-error">
   <li>C</li>
   <li>F</li>
   <li>A</li>
   <li>G</li>
   <li>B</li>
   <li>D
   <ul class="text-error">
          <li>D3</li>
          <li>D1</li>
          <li>D2
            <ul class="text-error">
              <li>D2-1</li>
              <li>D2-3</li>
              <li>D2-2</li>
              <li>D2-4</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>D5</li>
          <li>D4</li>
       </ul>
   </li>
   <li>E
   <ul class="text-error">
          <li>E1</li>
          <li>E3</li>
          <li>E4</li>
          <li>E2</li>
          <li>E5
            <ul class="text-error">
              <li>E5-1</li>
              <li>E5-4</li>
              <li>E5-2</li>
              <li>E5-3</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it skips the nested lists?

Comment: Well yes and no. This will sort each level for it self. "Say Goodbye" will be sorted above "Say Hello" in that specific <ul>. All levels are sorted without interfering with the others.

Comment: The reason that this works is that `jQuery.children('...')` only gets first level elements relative to the jQery object. To get ALL `<li>`-children one should use `jQuery.find('...')` instead, but that would break this code.

Answer (score 1):

You could create recursive function that will look for `ul` elements inside `li` and if it exists it will sort each nested `ul`.

```js
function sortHTML(el) {
  const li = el.find('> li');

  const sorted = li.sort((a, b) => {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text())
  })

  li.each(function() {
    const ul = $(this).find('ul');
    if (ul.length) {
      ul.each(function() {
        sortHTML($(this))
      })
    }
  })

  el.html(sorted)
}

sortHTML($('body > ul.text-error'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="text-error">
  <li>Brush your teeth</li>
  <li>Wash your hands</li>
  <li>Do your homework</li>
  <li>Do not use curse-words</li>
  <li id="files-errorPrincipals">Act polite:
    <ul class="text-error">
      <li class="file-error">Say Hello</li>
      <li class="file-error">Say Goodbye</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="files-error">Always remember:
    <ul id="files-error-list" class="text-error">
      <li class="file-error">Think for yourself</li>
      <li class="file-error">Think twice</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it says that li has no elements?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I was wrong, my selector should not have been body. but if you work in a more dynamic environment with different phases if you would run the code two times in a row it will not work

Comment: Could you recreate a example where it doesn't work in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You want to recursively work through the tree.

For that, you could depth-first or breadth-first search, but why over complicate matters?  jQuery has a recursive "find everything" function built-in!

**Updated**: Using your original sort function.  Why not! And added a cut-down code version.

I'm using a simple filter to only sort `.sort` items, so it doesn't take over the entire page.

```js
function sortItems(parent, childSelector) {
  var items = parent.children(childSelector).sort(function(a, b) {
    return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text())
  });
  parent.append(items);
}

$().ready(function () {
  // ".sort" filter to limit what it sorts, could be "ul" instead
  $('body').find(".sort").each(function () {
    sortItems($(this), "li");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="sort">
 <li>Brush your teeth</li>
 <li>Wash your hands</li>
 <li>Do your homework</li>
 <li>Do not use curse-words</li>
 <li>Act polite:
    <ul class="sort">
       <li>Say Hello</li>
       <li>Say Goodbye</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
 <li>Always remember:
    <ul class="sort">
      <li>Think for yourself</li>
      <li>Think twice</li>
    </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

A more minified version:

```
$().ready(function () {
  // ".sort" filter to limit what it sorts, could be "ul" instead
  // This is jQuery's recursive search function - "find(<filter>)".
  $('body').find(".sort").each(function () {
        // For each item we want to sort ("find().each()"), sort them.
        // Note: I'm explicitly filtering for "li" items to sort.
        var sortedChildren = $(this).children("li").sort(function(a, b) {
          return $(a).text().localeCompare($(b).text());
        });
        $(this).append(sortedChildren);
  });
});
```